# Place two H elements side by side just with css

Tags: html, css

I want to place these two "h" elements, BUT just the two "h" elements (no changes on the rest), side by side using just css, I don't want to change the html. (the reason is that there are two many html templates where I want the same result, so if it's possible to do it with css I can avoid overwriting and editing many html files.)

The "title" I want to achieve is a one-line title composed by the two elements (title and subtitle) separated by a pipe character ( | ) so also I can give one style each.

```
<div class="carousel-box">
    <h1 class="carousel-item-header h1 text-right">title</h1>
    <h2 class="carousel-item-subheader h1 text-right">subtitle</h2>
  <div class="carousel-item-bodytext">
    <p>Ignatenis molorro mi, que cone ne pliquunt ut odionet dolorerio rectur con cuptae la cori velit, nulluptaspe molorem. | Doloreped quias dia expeditatium resequis aut faccus andem eatia qui de ommo.</p>
  </div>
  <a href="http://hebotek.at" class="carousel-item-button btn btn-primary">
    <span>il is antur em quias</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Display them inline/inline-block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use their shared class to make them both display inline and use an `:after` on the heading to add the pipe:

```css
.h1 {
  display: inline;
}

.carousel-item-header:after {
  content: '|'
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-box">
    <h1 class="carousel-item-header h1 text-right">title</h1>
    <h2 class="carousel-item-subheader h1 text-right">subtitle</h2>
  <div class="carousel-item-bodytext">
    <p>Ignatenis molorro mi, que cone ne pliquunt ut odionet dolorerio rectur con cuptae la cori velit, nulluptaspe molorem. | Doloreped quias dia expeditatium resequis aut faccus andem eatia qui de ommo.</p>
  </div>
  <a href="http://hebotek.at" class="carousel-item-button btn btn-primary">
    <span>il is antur em quias</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

You can then adjust this to your needs.

Comment: Omg, I can't believe how simple it was haha. Thanks Alex. You totally understood what i meant.

Answer (score -1):

You can put `h1` and `h2` in a `div` and apply `display:flex` to that `div` like this:

```css
.hs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-box">
  <div class="hs">
    <h1 class="carousel-item-header h1 text-right">title</h1>
    <h2 class="carousel-item-subheader h1 text-right">subtitle</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item-bodytext">
    <p>Ignatenis molorro mi, que cone ne pliquunt ut odionet dolorerio rectur con cuptae la cori velit, nulluptaspe molorem. | Doloreped quias dia expeditatium resequis aut faccus andem eatia qui de ommo.</p>
  </div>
  <a href="http://hebotek.at" class="carousel-item-button btn btn-primary">
    <span>il is antur em quias</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: The OP states in their question they don't want to change the HTML if possible.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `inline` `display` property to display the text side by side:

```css
.text-right {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-box">
  <div class="hs">
    <h1 class="carousel-item-header h1 text-right">title</h1>
    <h2 class="carousel-item-subheader h1 text-right">subtitle</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item-bodytext">
    <p>Ignatenis molorro mi, que cone ne pliquunt ut odionet dolorerio rectur con cuptae la cori velit, nulluptaspe molorem. | Doloreped quias dia expeditatium resequis aut faccus andem eatia qui de ommo.</p>
  </div>
  <a href="http://hebotek.at" class="carousel-item-button btn btn-primary">
    <span>il is antur em quias</span>
  </a>
</div>
```